# Amazon EC2 ebs vs gp2 ami

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

It's probably a silly question, but I can't understand the difference between these 2 amazon linux 2 amis:

- ami-7105540e amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20180622.1-x86_64-ebs
- ami-b70554c8 amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20180622.1-x86_64-gp2

Judging by this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html), isn't `gp2` just another `ebs` instance type?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question isn't silly at all. In fact AWS's lack of documentation explaining the actual difference between the two is a bit surprising

#### TLDR;

If you're planning on switching to a faster SSD root volume at some point in the future but want to use Magnetic for now it would be better to use the `gp2` version of the AMI and then change the root volume to SSD sometime later

#### Some more Explanation

- `ami-b70554c8 amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20180622.1-x86_64-gp2` - The *recommended* root volume type is General Purpose SSD (gp2)
- `ami-7105540e amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20180622.1-x86_64-ebs` - The *recommended* root volume type is Magnetic

However this isn't set in stone so you can still interchange between them (I've used the `gp2` version with a Magnetic storage in the past without any issues)

I couldn't find any official documentation as to the actual difference between the two AMI versions but the `gp2` version most likely has SSD related optimizations added already to the OS

So if you envision switching to SSD at some point in future but want to start with a Magnetic volume it might be better to just use the `gp2` optimized AMI right from the start. It probably has some optimizations not relevant to Magnetic volumes but it might be more future proof in case you want to have a faster root volume later

Answer (score 16):

The took the AMI in two types of Volumes.

amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20180622.1-x86_64-ebs - ami-7105540e. This has **Magnetic Volume** type for its root volume.

ami-b70554c8 amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20180622.1-x86_64-gp2. This has **SSD Volume type**  for its root volume.

How can we identify this?

- Go to EC2.
- Launch Instance
- Select the mentioned AMI
- Select any instance Type.
- Choose the VPC, subnet and etc.
- Next it'll show the Boot Disk size, there you can see its in SSD or Magnetic.

To learn about Volume tyes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html

Comment: Sounds reasonable but can you point me to a relevant documentation please?

Comment: That isn't completely true. Even though it is set as Magnetic/SSD you can still change them to one or the other